# Capturing all occurences of a repeated group in a string and reference them for substitution

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have following regex that matches any number in the string and returns it in the group, which then i replace with another text.

For the sample string:

```
/text_1/123456/text_2
```

With `/^(.*[^0-9])+([0-9]{3,}+)+(.*)$` and using substitution like `$1captured_group$3` i get my desired result i.e. `/text_1/captured_group/text_2`

However for scenarios where the capturing groups appears more than once in the give string such as:

```
/text_1/123456/text_2/789011
/text_1/123456/text_2/789011/abc/12345
```

The given regex would only capture last group i.e. `789011` and `12345` respectively. However, what i want is to capture all of the groups and be able to reference them later to replace them.

An explanation given on `regex101.com` i beleive addresses my scenario:

```
A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data.
```

However, i am not sure how to `Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations` and later reference all the matched values?

Comment: If you want to match multiple occurrences you need to get rid of the anchors (`^`, `$`) and add a global (`g`)  modifier, such as [`/\b[0-9]{3,}\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/e5db4t/1)

Comment: There are regex flavors where  you can those matches, but what is the tool or language and what do you want to accomplish for the example data? Is there a pattern or structure that must be followed for the whole string?

Comment: @The fourth bird I am using them in a nginx map module, and recalling them using backreferences later like this:  https://regex101.com/r/upx2hC/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hao Wu commented:

> *"If you want to match multiple occurrences you need to get rid of the anchors (`^`, `$`) and add a global (`g`) modifier, such as `/\b[0-9]{3,}\b/g`"*

As for storing matches and referencing them for later use, you could have an array of objects wherein each object has the match and an array of two indices -- the first index being the index of the start of the match and the second index being the index of the end of the match:

```
// string = `123`
{match: 123, indices: [0, 2]}
```

In the example below, the function `tagMatches(str, rgx)` uses [`.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) method.

```js
const tagMatches = (str, rgx) => {
  const matches = str.matchAll(rgx);
  let result = [];
  for (const match of matches) {
    result.push({"match": +match[0], "indices": [match.index, match.index + match.length]});
  }
  return result;
}

const string = `utfuduyiutcv fvtycy 1sdtyveaf 678900 amsiofjsogifn979/125487/`;
const regexp = /\b(\d){3,}\b/g;

const tagged = tagMatches(string, regexp)

console.log(tagged);

console.log("first match: "+tagged[0].match);
console.log("second match start: "+tagged[1].indices[0]);
console.log("first match end: "+tagged[0].indices[1]);
```

Comment: Thankyou. I get that we get the answers in a array however what i am confused is how to reference this array using regex syntax as I am using this regex in a nginx map module, and recalling them using backreferences later like this:  https://regex101.com/r/upx2hC/1

Comment: Ah, add the ngnix and Python tags, sorry I don't know enough Python and nothing about ngnix.